# PowerShell how to add-type from GAC

Tags: powershell

I try to call `Add-Type -AssemblyName myassembly`, and `myassembly` has been registered into GAC, but I always got following error:

> Cannot add type. The assembly 'myassembly' could not be found.

I know how to `Add-Type` from a file location, is there a way to `Add-Type` from **GAC** conveniently?

Comment: Use full assembly name.

Comment: @PetSerAl I forget to test full assembly name, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load from the GAC you need the fully qualified assembly name:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0", Colture=netural, PublicKeyToken=89956cdc9090cc76"
```

And yea, it's really annoying!

Comment: There is some spell erros. It should be `"Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=netural, PublicKeyTokwn=89956cdc9090cc76"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Web.Deployment')` Yes I [know its obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadwithpartialname?view=netframework-4.8) and you should use [Load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load).

Often you may not have the full name and don't care to enumerate the assemblies in the GAC. This will allow you to load the assembly. If you care, you can then pull the fullname to use with Load() for your scripts going forward.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('system.web.security')
PS c:\> [System.Web.Security.Membership].Assembly.Fullname
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy it to another computer, you have to unblock it.